# Terraform, AWS, Databricks Error: cannot create instance profile: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-databricks

I'm trying to create and mount on databricks S3 buckets.
File structure

- Main (Parent) Module - Create VPC, call modules Workspace and
  S3_bucket
- Child module 1 - Workspace - creates Cross Account IAM role, Root bucket and Databricks workspace
- Child module 2 - S3_bucket - creates Cross account policy and role for S3 buckets and creates and mounts buckets themselves

The module S3 bucket is based on an example from here
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/0.3.3/docs/resources/aws_s3_mount
The only difference - I separated parts where I create IAM roles and policies and parts, where I create S3 buckets and mount them

Here is a snippet from S3_bucket_policy.tf

```
data "databricks_aws_assume_role_policy" "s3_arp" {
    external_id = var.dbx_account_id
}

// Step 9: Grant Databricks full access to VPC resources
resource "aws_iam_role" "s3_cross_account" {
  #for_each = aws_iam_role.s3_cross_account == null ? [  var.aws_s3_cxrossaccount_iam_role_name ] : []
  name               = var.prefix != null ? "${var.prefix}-${var.aws_s3_cxrossaccount_iam_role_name}" : "${var.aws_s3_cxrossaccount_iam_role_name}"

  assume_role_policy = data.databricks_aws_assume_role_policy.s3_arp.json
  description        = "Grants Databricks full access to VPC resources"
  tags               = var.tags
}

# resource "time_sleep" "wait10s_3" {
#   depends_on = [aws_iam_role.s3_cross_account]
#   create_duration = "10s"
# }

// Step 11: Register cross-account role for multi-workspace scenario (only if you're using multi-workspace setup)
resource "databricks_mws_credentials" "s3_dbx_cred" {
  #for_each = databricks_mws_credentials.s3_dbx_cred == null ? [  var.dbx_s3_credential_name ] : []
  # provider         = databricks.mws
  # depends_on       = [ time_sleep.wait10s_3 ]
  account_id       = var.dbx_account_id
  credentials_name = var.prefix != null ? "${var.prefix}-${var.dbx_s3_credential_name}" : "${var.dbx_s3_credential_name}" 
  role_arn         = aws_iam_role.s3_cross_account.arn
}

// Step 12: Register your data role with instance profile
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "iam_ip" {
  #for_each = aws_iam_instance_profile.iam_ip == null ? [  var.aws_s3_instance_profile_name ] : []
  name = var.prefix != null ? "${var.prefix}-${var.aws_s3_instance_profile_name}" : "${var.aws_s3_instance_profile_name}"
  role = aws_iam_role.s3_cross_account.name
  tags               = var.tags
}

# resource "time_sleep" "wait10s_4" {
#   depends_on = [aws_iam_instance_profile.iam_ip]
#   create_duration = "10s"
# }

// Step 13: Register instance profile at Databrickshsozialhilfe 
resource "databricks_instance_profile" "dbx_ip" {
  #for_each = databricks_instance_profile.dbx_ip == null ? [ "OK" ] : []
  #depends_on = [ time_sleep.wait10s_4 ]
  instance_profile_arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.iam_ip.arn
}

// Step 14: now you can do `%fs ls /mnt/experiments` in notebooks
// https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/mount#migration-from-other-mount-resources
resource "databricks_secret" "mount_config" {
  #for_each = databricks_secret.mount_config == null ? [ "OK" ] : []
  key   = "mount-config"
  scope = "AWS"


  string_value = jsonencode({
    "s3" = {
      "region"  = var.aws_region
      "endpoint" = "s3.${var.aws_region}.amazonaws.com"
      "enable_multipart_upload" = true
      "max_retry_count" = 10
      "max_parallel_uploads" = 5
    }
  })
}
```

Last two resourcefail with he message **Error: cannot create secret: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL**

Here is contents from debug log file

```
2023-04-11T17:55:20.055+0200 [DEBUG] module.s3_buckets.databricks_secret.mount_config: applying the planned Create change
2023-04-11T17:55:20.056+0200 [INFO]  Starting apply for module.s3_buckets.databricks_instance_profile.dbx_ip
2023-04-11T17:55:20.057+0200 [DEBUG] module.s3_buckets.databricks_instance_profile.dbx_ip: applying the planned Create change
2023-04-11T17:55:21.441+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.14.2.exe: POST /api/2.0/instance-profiles/add
> {
>   "instance_profile_arn": "arn:aws:iam::072498559190:instance-profile/vsemouch-dbx-aws-aws-s3-instance-profile"
> }
< HTTP/2.0 405 Method Not Allowed
[non-JSON document of 333 bytes]: timestamp=2023-04-11T17:55:21.436+0200
2023-04-11T17:55:21.441+0200 [ERROR] provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.14.2.exe: Response contains error diagnostic: diagnostic_detail= diagnostic_severity=ERROR tf_proto_version=5.3 tf_provider_addr=registry.terraform.io/databricks/databricks tf_req_id=71bf8cf3-b5b7-e56d-bb83-99ac3496d85d tf_rpc=ApplyResourceChange @module=sdk.proto diagnostic_summary="cannot create instance profile: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL" tf_resource_type=databricks_instance_profile @caller=/home/runner/work/terraform-provider-databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:55 timestamp=2023-04-11T17:55:21.436+0200
2023-04-11T17:55:21.473+0200 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.14.2.exe: POST /api/2.0/secrets/put
> {
>   "key": "mount-config",
>   "scope": "AWS",
>   "string_value": "**REDACTED**"
> }
< HTTP/2.0 405 Method Not Allowed
[non-JSON document of 323 bytes]: timestamp=2023-04-11T17:55:21.472+0200
2023-04-11T17:55:21.473+0200 [ERROR] provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v1.14.2.exe: Response contains error diagnostic: tf_resource_type=databricks_secret tf_rpc=ApplyResourceChange @module=sdk.proto diagnostic_detail= diagnostic_summary="cannot create secret: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL" tf_provider_addr=registry.terraform.io/databricks/databricks @caller=/home/runner/work/terraform-provider-databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:55 diagnostic_severity=ERROR tf_proto_version=5.3 tf_req_id=07d5f476-3415-0626-c2fa-b8ad9b3b580f timestamp=2023-04-11T17:55:21.472+0200
2023-04-11T17:55:21.634+0200 [ERROR] vertex "module.s3_buckets.databricks_secret.mount_config" error: cannot create secret: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
2023-04-11T17:55:21.682+0200 [ERROR] vertex "module.s3_buckets.databricks_instance_profile.dbx_ip" error: cannot create instance profile: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
2023-04-11T17:55:21.798+0200 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2023-04-11T17:55:21.817+0200 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/databricks/databricks/1.14.2/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-databricks_v1.14.2.exe pid=96460
2023-04-11T17:55:21.817+0200 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
```

I would be be very happy if one of you, experts would help me here.

Comment: See https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/issues/2183

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two different provider configurations for different resources:

- account level - for creation of the workspace, and related objects
- workspace level - for creation of secret scopes, secrets, etc. that are inside the workspace.

And then corresponding resources should have different provider configurations specified in each resource.  And you also need to have explicit dependencies.

```
// account level
provider "databricks" {
  alias    = "mws"
  host     = "https://accounts.cloud.databricks.com"
  username = var.databricks_account_username
  password = var.databricks_account_password
}

//workspace level
provider "databricks" {
  alias = "mws"
  host  = module.e2.workspace_url
  token = module.e2.token_value
}
```

and use it as following:

- account level objects

```
resource "databricks_mws_workspaces" "this" {
  provider = databricks.mws
....
}
```

- workspace objects:

```
resource "databricks_secret" "mount_config" {
  provider = databricks.ws
  key   = "mount-config"
  scope = "AWS"
  string_value = "..."
  depends_on = [databricks_mws_workspaces.this]
}
```

P.S. Also check the [troubleshooting guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/troubleshooting#data-resources-and-authentication-is-not-configured-errors).

Comment: Looks like a typo as both providers have the same `mws` alias which is clearly not right. In the example, the workspace provider was referred to as `ws` which is probably what's intended in the second workspace alias. Sadly edits of less than 6 chars, which this would be as it's only 1, aren't allowed to be suggested.